# How to show 4 Web Parts in one Div with scroll

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

I want to display 4 web parts in one div with scroll how can i do this using jQuery in SPD. Its a Wiki page.

Comment: You can create one page layout with one web part zone and add that web part zone in your div tag. Create page using that web part zone and then add 4 web parts in the page. Now your all web parts will be within your div tag. Give css with height and overflow property to div tag.

Comment: Do you have to use a wiki page? Wiki pages don't have web part zones and they are difficult to work with, use a web part page if you can and follow the advice given above about page layouts. you can also use the design manager to create web part zones.

Comment: I want to apply this changes on my Wiki page not  web part page so please give any solution related to wiki page.